# Converting an empty string to a date, and then back

Tags: vb.net, validation, string

I'm trying to do some validation testing in VB.NET.

```
 If Entity.WeekEndDate.ToString = String.Empty Then
            ErrorList.Add(New cValidationError("id", "Incorrect Week End Date"))
```

Where WeekEndDate is of type Date. When I originally build the object, how can I insert a value into WeekEndDate that will generate an empty string(ie. "") when converted from a Date to a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be better to use `MinValue` to represent an invalid date:

```
If Entity.WeekEndDate = DateTime.MinValue Then 
     ErrorList.Add(New cValidationError("id", "Incorrect Week End Date"))
```

As a rule, you shouldn't be converting dates to strings and then comparing them. Compare as the original datatype (in this case, DateTime).

Comment: i believe the out-of-the-box winforms date controls have problems with null dates...

Comment: I didn't originally write this validation object, so I was unsure as to what they were trying to check against. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
WeekEndDate = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it nullable and compare to null instead.

MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981315(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no date value that will produce an empty string when calling `ToString`. If you need this functionality, the column must be nullable in your database and your entity must use the `Nullable(Of DateTIme)` type for the value.

You can then say:

```
If Entity.WeekEndDate Is Nothing Then
    ErrorList>Add(new cValidationError("id", "Incorrect Week End Date"))
```

And to produce the error, just say:

```
Entity.WeekEndDate = Nothing
```